# Unique way of invoking a method call

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to understand why the following method call needs (MKPinAnnotationView *) after the equal sign.

This method's definition can be found in the MKMapView.h header.

```
/ Used by the delegate to acquire an already allocated annotation view, in lieu of allocating a new one.
- (MKAnnotationView *)dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

When I look at the sample calls for this method I see the following syntax:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *view = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:kPinIdentifier];
```

If the method returns MKAnnotationView object; why can I not write the following method call:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *view = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:kPinIdentifier];
```

If to the left of the equal sign I have an MKAnnotationView object, what is the purpose of the (MKPinAnnotationView*) after the equal sign and before the method call?

Also, what is it on the method's definition that is enforcing the use of the  (MKPinAnnotationView*) piece after the equal sign?

Fortunately the code works with the special syntax, but since I have never seen this type of method call, my head is wondering if I am missing something else when it comes to method calls and initializers.

Comment: Think about inheritance. You know that a kangaroo is a mammal, but is a mammal a kangaroo?

Answer (score 1):

It's called type casting, and it's used because the method `dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:` returns an object of type `MKAnnotationView`, and you want to use an instance of `MKPinAnnotationView` which is a subclass of `MKAnnotationView`. This cast allows you access any methods or properties added to the subclass from the methods return value.

Answer (score 1):

It's a type cast. The method returns a `MKAnnotationView *`, but the caller is casting it to a `MKPinAnnotationView *`. The caller is assuming these are compatible types. For example maybe `MKPinAnnotationView` is a subclass of `MKAnnotationView`.